# Is there a simple way to play a rtmp stream in java?

Tags: java, mp4, rtmp

I want to play an MP4 videon streamed over rtmp protocol in java.

I found a few rtmp libraries (yuv, red5), but nothing on mp4 display.

Is there a (possibly simple and maybe platform-indenpendent) solution to do it in java?

Answer (score 1):

Most rtmp streams in my experience tend not to be MP4. There's nothing particularly clever about rtmp streaming though, and if you really can't find anything to fit your needs the way to go is to get hold of a copy of rtmpdump, rip the stream to file and play it.

BTW I'm playing with the IBM MP4 sdk toolkit at the moment,  downloadable from http://www.alphaworks.ibm.com/tech/tk4mpeg4 . Seems straightforward enough, dled, unzipped and had the Swing demo app playing MP4s in NetBeans in under 5 minutes. If the stream you're talking to is genuinely MP4 you could probably figure out how to hotwire it to the stream fairly quickly from what I'm seeing of the IBM MP4 API.